# Android: ListView and per list item onClick action

Tags: android, listview, actionlistener

I've populated a Listview, adapting data from database. And of course per list item have same layout. Inside this layout there are some buttons, checkboxs and other widgets.

Now I want to set onClickListenser. How to achieve that?

Here is the overview:
[image]

**What I have:**

```
private void populateListView(){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor alarms = db.getAllAlarms();

    startManagingCursor(alarms);
    String[] time = new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_TIME};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.timeTitle};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.per_alarm_activity,
            alarms,
            time,
            toViewIDs
            );

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allAlarmsView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTitle);
    mAmPmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amPmTextView);
    mAlarmOnOff = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.alarmOnOff);
    mRepeatCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.repeatCheckBox);
    mDrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrowDown);
    mUp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrowUp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                CheckBox mRepeatCheck  =((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.repeatCheckBox));
                //same code goes for othe buttons, imageview etc
    }
});
```